# Actual size of a UserControl having ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Actual Size of UserControl before rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665475/getting-actual-size-of-usercontrol-before-rendering)
>   [How to override MeasureOverride to find the size of ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844994/how-to-override-measureoverride-to-find-the-size-of-itemscontrol)

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844994/how-to-override-measureoverride-to-find-the-size-of-itemscontrol) before which essentially boils down to:

How can I get the actual size of a UserControl having an ItemsControl to which items are dynamically added?

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844994/how-to-override-measureoverride-to-find-the-size-of-itemscontrol) overriding `MeasureOverride` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665475/getting-actual-size-of-usercontrol-before-rendering), but it is not helping.

Comment: I have tried suggestions given there. That's the reason I linked that question.

Comment: Rather than asking the same question again, why not try adding a 'bounty' to your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but look at the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx

Comment: `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` are not calculated until after the controls have been rendered. Based on the linked question, I think the OP wants to get the size before they get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I allways wait for the sizechanged event of the control for which I need the `ActualHeight` and the `ActualWidth` properties.

So, hookup this event to your user control and then react in handler on `e.NewSize`.